# How to change navbar/container width? Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The default width for my navbar is too wide `1170px`. I would like to reduce it down to `940px` - but I want to keep the responsiveness.

I tried to change the container width in CSS and it looks ok with a large browser, but the rest of the page falls apart when viewing for mobile sizes.

Is this the correct property or is there something else?

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
  max-width: 1170px;
}
```

Here is my navbar code

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site Name</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#shop">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#showcase">Showcase</a></li>
            <li><a href="#help">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="#my account">My Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#cart">Cart <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 55):

I just solved this issue myself. You were on the right track.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container{
        max-width: 970px;
    }
}
```

Here we say: On viewports 1200px or larger - set container max-width to 970px. This will overwrite the standard class that currently sets max-width to 1170px for that range.

NOTE: Make sure you include this AFTER the bootstrap.css stuff (everyone has made this little mistake in the past).

Hope this helps.. good luck!

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that if you only want to do this on your navbar that you can do so by nesting the snippet above within `.navbar`.

Comment: Also don't forget `.container-fluid`

Comment: How would I do this if I did not want ALL of my containers to abide by this rule? Should I just give it an id and then target that in my CSS file? I'm sure that would work, but I'm curious if it's the 'right way' to do this.

Comment: @ohhh that should work. In my head, a class makes more sense though.

Answer (score 2):

Container widths will drop down to 940 pixels for viewports less than 992 pixels. If you *really* don’t want containers larger than 940 pixels wide, then go to the [Bootstrap customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) page, and set `@container-lg-desktop` to either `@container-desktop` or hard-coded `940px`.

Comment: I don't understand. I went to the customize page, changed the "@container-lg-desktop" to 940, downloaded the zip, replaced my bootstrap.css with the new bootstrap css and my page still displays the larger width.

Comment: I imagine that’s a bug with the build script then, as the help text states: “Define the maximum width of `.container` for different screen sizes.”

Comment: There's has to be something I can do. Many of the sites showcased at the bootstrap website have a width of 940px, because this is what most designers are aiming for. So it must be possible.

Comment: The Bootstrap framework is responsive by default. Although 940 pixels may have been the standard designers have used for the past few years, like the past few years desktop resolutions are getting bigger and bigger to where 1170 pixels isn’t too monstrous.

Answer (score 1):

The `.navbar-static-top` you are using forces your `navbar` to become full-width. Remove that class and you will get a resizable `navbar`. Then, you can wrap it in a `span#` of the size you want.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
        <div class="navbar">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does navbar-fixed-bottom force it too?

Answer (score 1):

just simple:

```
.navbar{
    width:65% !important;
    margin:0px auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

or,

```
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top{
    width:65% !important;
    margin:0px auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Hope it works (at least, for future searchers)

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to do it is to change the width on the online customizer here:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

download the recompiled source, overwrite the existing bootstrap dist dir, and reload (mind the browser cache!!!)

All your changes will be retained in the .json configuration file

To apply again the all the changes just upload the json file and you are ready to go

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with more dynamic screen resolution/sizes, instead of hardcoding the size in pixels you can change the width to a percentage of the media width as such

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container{
        max-width: 70%;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello this working you try! in your case is .navbar-fixed-top{}

```
.navbar-fixed-bottom{
    width:1200px;
    left:20%;
}
```